# IntelliJ can't find files from test/resources/subFolder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, classpath

I'm having a problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Community Edition), when running a unit test, can't find a resource class from src/test/resources folder.Based on various stackoverflow links I have tried below things but all in vain. I am using Windows 11. Is there any other suggestion to make it work?

1)
Right click on resources folder > Mark directory as ... > Unmark as Resources Root
Right click on resources folder > Mark directory as ... > Test Resources Root

2)adding required folder as a dependency for the module in the module settings. Adding screenshot of my module setting as well.

Also things are working in eclipse so there is no issue of code.

Java method(getObjectFromFile) using to access file

```
private static final String basePath = "src/test/resources/data/";

private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

 static {
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
}

public static <T> T getObjectFromFile(String relativePath, Class<T> clazz) {
try {
  return objectMapper.readValue(new File(basePath + relativePath), clazz);
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("Error while parsing JSON: {},{}", relativePath, e);
  return null;
}
}
```

Test Configuration[image]

Error:

```
 10:02:32.107 [main] ERROR 
 com.sams.ng.oms.payment.processor.util.ParserUtil - Error while 
 parsing JSON: 
 response/Response.json,java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
 src\test\resources\data\response\Response.json (The system 
 cannot 
 find the path specified)
```

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to try to access the resource? Please edit your question to include that, and the full stack trace of any exception.

Comment: I didn't added code because it is working in eclipse and also in my colleagues IDE(intellij) so there is no issue of code. Do you still need it ? I can add

Comment: How are you running your program? The path you are using is relative, so the file will only be found if you run from the directory above `src`.

Comment: Customer customer= ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile("response/Response.json", Customer.class);

Comment: adding test config screenshot

Comment: Please try solutions from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-files.html